# Pyspark code giving wierd whitespace error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, whitespace, removing-whitespace, trailing-whitespace

[image: Error]

When I ran this query, `zip code` is getting some hidden whitespace which pushes over to data-source column. Tried `trim` function and `trim` with carriage return, whitespace is not getting removed. Any suggestions?

Note: window partition was used to get zip code

```
select 
      distinct x, 
      first_value(zip_code) 
      over(partition by x order by date_time_closed desc) as zip_code 
from table
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try selecting `hex(zip_code)` to see the whole value?

Comment: @mazaneicha Please help here 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71700734/interpretting-hex-value-in-pyspark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing white space in column values of SQL o/p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666071/removing-white-space-in-column-values-of-sql-o-p)