# Removing white space in column values of SQL o/p

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, whitespace, blank-line

Not able to remove white space from SQL query output used in pyspark code.

I tried, trim,ltrim,rtrim,replace (multiple nested also) and regex replace. Any other suggestion.

When trim was used in sql side alone, it worked. But when it is used inside pyspark query no change

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @anky tried,not getting trimmed

Comment: compare_query="""

select 'pspk' as data_source, customer_city
from old_ticket_df
where ticketlineid='f31fd351-3036-4f71-b4e5-cbdf3039429c'


"""

compare_df=spark.sql(compare_query)

compare_df=compare_df.withColumn("customer_city_trim",trim(compare_df['customer_city']))

compare_df.show(truncate=False)

Comment: It looks more like special characters to me than whitespace.