# Interpreting hex value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hex, whitespace

I was querying values from two tables, which were joined, to find out the reason for mismatch in `pyspark`.

Joining columns from the tables seems to have extra space in one column.

I tried `trim` functions(multiple combinations) to remove the white space but it was futile.

There was one suggestion to try with `hex()` function. Below is the code and output for the same. Can someone tell me how to interpret hex?

```
compare_query="""
(
select coalesce(upper(trim(b.cleaned)),upper(trim(a.tz_brandname))) as tz_brandname_mapped, 
b.source,length(b.source),hex(b.source),
a.productbrand,length(a.productbrand),hex(a.productbrand)
from ticket a
left join brand_mapping b
on trim(a.productbrand)=trim(b.source)
where ticketid='xxx'
and ticketlineid='xxx'
and storeid='xxx'
and dateclosed='xxx'
)
"""

compare_df=spark.sql(compare_query)

compare_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
FloatProgress(value=0.0, bar_style='info', description='Progress:', layout=Layout(height='25px', width='50%'),…
+-------------------+------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|tz_brandname_mapped|source|length(source)|hex(source) |productbrand|length(productbrand)|hex(productbrand)|
+-------------------+------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|SOURCE CANNABIS    |SOURCE|6             |534F55524345| SOURCE     |7                   |20534F55524345   |
+-------------------+------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: you can use the below link to understand the hex representation of each character in your example  20534F55524345 - there is 20 value that represents space in hex, the rest of the values seems to match.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html

Comment: `hex(productbrand)=20534F55524345`: **20- space**, 53- 'S', '4F' - 'O', 55- 'U' etc. etc.